# Is this a valid use of a WCF Service Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have the following scenario:

- Program P (can take upto 30 minutes to complete) on box X.
- WinForms application on box Y - this gathers the input criteria for P.
- Because P takes so long I want it to always run on box X and not Y.

I was adviced to try using a WCF Service Application on X. Send a message to X from Y via a service contract and this would then fire program P.

Is this a valid use of a WCF Service App project?

---

I have followed these two walk-throughs:

1. [Create a WCF service](http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-create-wcf-web-service-in.html)
2. [Create a console app to consume WCF service](http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-consume-wcf-web-service-in.html)

I now have two projects that seem to talk to each other. I can run the following code from the console app, the method `moveData` that is in the WCF project successfully updates a database with some information based on the parameters:

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {
                Service1Client sc = new Service1Client();
                sc.moveData(0,1);
                sc.Close();
        }
```

**I'm very new to this sort of technology - please bear in mind re. the following questions:**
It only works when I've got the WCF project open or running in Visual Studio - is this as expected? in other words should the consuming app throw an error if the WCF is not running?
i.e. If I close the instance of Vis Studio with the WCF project and then try running the consuming application I get an error `System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException was unhandled There was no endpoint listening at...followed by address of service`
How do I let box X make use of this WCF? What do need to install or deploy to that box?

app.config in the consumer console app looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://....svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what does the .config file look like I have a feeling that this issues has to deal with the config settings http:// https:// , etc..

Comment: If an operation takes 30 minutes to complete, it would be better to run it on a Windows Service.

Comment: make sure you don't have duplicate entries in the .config file as well.. I'd love to see what the app.config file looks like

Comment: @DJKRAZE app.config in the consumer console application; or web.config in the WCF project ?

Comment: @Steven are they easy to set up?

Comment: Where you are defining and or reading from your WCF Bindings..

Search for this line in the config file <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract=" it's then post what it looks like those config setting

Comment: @DJKRAZE I've added to the OP

Comment: I am going to post an example of a simple service below as well as how you can create or copy the code to setup one to test I think you have config setting that's off or incorrect..

Comment: @5arx ...my thoughts aswell - I assume you evened it out? thanks

Comment: (although it isn't the most specific question)

Comment: I thought the downvote was a bit harsh too

Comment: @DJKRAZE ok - but I followed the instructions in those walk-throughs word-for-word. I used `SvcUtil.exe` to create the file `Service1.cs` and the XML in the config file. It runs fine when the WCF project is open in another instance of VS but doesn't work when it is closed ...maybe this is the correct behaviour? Do I need to make this service run in the background on the server somehow?

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 I thought it might get downvoted when posting - sometimes I need an answer or opinion and I'll post knowing some down-votes are a possibility

Comment: Sounds like you are wanting to creating a Windows Service then

Comment: I gave you an UP Vote because I think this is a very good question and sometimes it's something very simple that one may be over looking

Comment: @DJKRAZE ... I'm at the sandpit stage of a big project; just experimenting with lots of bits to see if they work and then see if they will hang together ok - so I'll create a Windows Service and see what that is like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the other suggestions, a windows service is easy to build and setup.  You can even set it to auto start when the server (BOX X) is started

here is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/76477d2t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and a [Code Project tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample) to get you started.

Essentially:

```
public class UserService1 : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase  
{

    public UserService1() 
    {
        this.ServiceName = "MyService2";
        this.CanStop = true;
        this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        this.AutoLog = true;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(new UserService1());
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Insert code here to define processing.
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    { 
        // Whatever is required to stop processing
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Then you can persist the data you process on a database or on a file system or wherever, and expose the data over a WCF service, which your client (console app) can then consume.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code for a sample on how you can create this using WCF and a link to the SRC Code as well

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults" name="TestService.Service">
      <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=
            "TransportSecurity" contract="TestService.IService"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
            name="MetadataBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="returnFaults">
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
       <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
       <serviceTimeouts/>
   </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
       <binding name="TransportSecurity">
             <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
              </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
 <diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" 
    maxMessagesToLog="300" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
    logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
  </diagnostics>
 </system.serviceModel>

//Contract Description
[ServiceContract]
interface IService
{
  [OperationContract]
   string TestCall();
}

//Implementation
public class Service:IService
{
  public string TestCall()
  {
      return "You just called a WCF webservice On SSL
                    (Transport Layer Security)";
  }
}

//Tracing and message logging
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
    switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
         <listeners>
           <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
            <add name="xml"/>
         </listeners>
         </source>
    </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
          <add initializeData="C:\Service.svclog" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xml"/>
         </sharedListeners>
       <trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Source Code you can Download for this sample to try on your own.. follow the same steps to get your service to work as well 
This uses SSL by the way
[WCF Transport Layer Security using wsHttpBinding and SSL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18645/WCF-Transport-Layer-Security-using-wsHttpBinding-a#xx2242292xx)

Comment: +1 FOR ALL THE INFO. It's not just a case of copy and paste this code into my projects is it? I assume I'll need to read around it all a bit?

Comment: Copy paste for a simple test would work if you created a separate WCF Service.. but the link would allow you to download the full working code that you can mess around with and learn how to work with WCF by debugging / stepping thru the code.. it's a great learning tool as well when you have full working SRC

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create a Windows service that watches a database for messages to process stuff.  The service can then just always be running on your server (which I assume is box X).  WCF services can start a long running process, but probably should not host it.  Of course I'm assuming a WCF service hosted by Asp.Net.  You can build a Windows service that hosts WCF as well, which would eliminate the need for the service to monitor a message database.

Comment: originally I was thinking of just having a daemon console app on the server always checking for new rows being added to a database table ....but was advised this might be a smarter route. Are windows services easy to set up?

Comment: @whytheq Yes, basically you can do so from an administrative command prompt using `installutil`.